# Social Media Links on homepage - within posts/post loop

Tags: permalinks, links

On my WordPress site I've got a social sharing bar that I created myself. Here's a picture of the social sharing bar: http://d.pr/i/ucSG - I have the social sharing links included within 'index.php' between:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript">!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div><!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. --><script type="text/javascript">(function() { var po document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true; po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s); })();</script>

<? } endwhile; else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

When I go to share a link it gives me the URL off my website and not the permalink for the post. It works fine when I view the post and try this, but when I'm on the homepage it just gives me the permalink of my website. How do I get it to share the current post link that it's clicked on?

I don't understand why it's not showing the permalink as it's within the posts loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be in `header.php` or `single.php` and not index ...these are the correct parts of the theme that get called with every post or page.  That should fix part of the problem.

Also ... With [Twitter Tweet buttons](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#Examples), for example, you can have extra meta such as the `data-URL` and echo your post permalink I also use `data-count` as most of my permalinks are shortened and you want your click stats to follow the full post URL.

This is how I do it on my site:

```
<div class="wpse61568">
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-counturl=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?> data-count="horizontal" data-via="damiensaunders" rel="me">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
```

**header.php with conditional tag**

```
<?php if ( !is_single() ){ ?>
<div class="wpse61568_2">
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-counturl=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?> data-count="horizontal" data-via="damiensaunders" rel="me">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have different settings in single.php for the post itself, is there any way around this? E.g. use single.php for both maybe? - Also, I got the Twitter one working with what you have, what about Facebook and G+, do they have anything similar?

Comment: Yes you can ... Conditional Tags are the way forward ... i use this snippet to not show social buttons in the header if you're viewing a single-post `<?php if ( !is_single() ){ ?>`   see also http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: I used your technique, got them all working, thank you.

Comment: glad to help :)